# How to get distinct values from multiple columns in GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, query

Is there a way to get distinct values from multiple columns in geotools?

I know I can get unique values from a column like this:

```
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(layer);
Query query = new Query(layer, Filter.INCLUDE, new String[] { "PROPERTY_A", 
"PROPERTY_B", "PROPERTY_C" });
UniqueVisitor visitor = new UniqueVisitor("PROPERTY_A");
SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures( query );
collection.accepts(visitor, null);
Set set = visitor.getResult()
```

But what I need is an equivalent to `select distinct PROPERTY_A, PROPERTY_B, PROPERTY_C`.

**Edit:**
I've tried to get unique values from the first column, and then create cql filters with the unique values from the first column to query unique values from the second column and so on, an then join it all in the end. But the performance, as expected, is very poor.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem, the simplest solution I can think of is to extend `UniqueVisitor` to handle more than one column. So something like:

```
package org.geotools.feature.visitor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.opengis.feature.Feature;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory;
import org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression;

public class UniquesVisitor extends UniqueVisitor {
  List<Expression> expressions = new ArrayList<>();
  //implement other constructors as needed
  public UniquesVisitor(String[] strings) {

    super((String) null);
    FilterFactory factory = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(null);
    for (String col : strings) {
      expressions.add(factory.property(col));
    }

  }

  @Override
  public List<Expression> getExpressions() {
    return expressions;
  }

  public void visit(Feature feature) {
    Object[] values = new Object[expressions.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < expressions.size(); i++) {
      Expression expr = expressions.get(i);
      Object value = expr.evaluate(feature);
      values[i] = value;
    }
    Iterator<Object[]> itr = set.iterator();
    boolean contains = false;
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
      if(Arrays.equals(values, itr.next())) {
        contains=true;
      }
    }
    boolean skips = false;
    itr = skipped.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
      if(Arrays.equals(values, itr.next())) {
        skips=true;
      }
    }
    if (!contains && !skips) {
      if (currentItem >= startIndex && currentItem < (startIndex + maxFeatures)) {
        set.add(values);
      } else {
        skipped.add(values);
      }
      currentItem++;
    }
  }

}
```

Can be called with something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder tBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    tBuilder.setName("test");
    tBuilder.add("colA", String.class);
    tBuilder.add("colB", String.class);
    tBuilder.add("colC", String.class);
    SimpleFeatureType schema = tBuilder.buildFeatureType();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder fBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(schema);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });
    SimpleFeature f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "A", "B", "C" });
    f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "A", "B", "A" });
    f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "A", "B", "A" });
    f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "A", "A", "C" });
    f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);
    fBuilder.addAll(new String[] { "B", "B", "B" });
    f = fBuilder.buildFeature(null);
    features.add(f);

    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = DataUtilities.collection(features);
    try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = collection.features()) {
      int k=0;
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature next = itr.next();
        System.out.print(""+k+": ");
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
          System.out.print(next.getAttribute(i)+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        k++;
      }
    }

    UniquesVisitor visitor = new UniquesVisitor(new String[] {"colA","colB","colC"}) ;

    try {
      collection.accepts(visitor, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    CalcResult res = visitor.getResult();
    for (Object value : res.toArray()) {
      for(int i=0;i<((Object[])value).length;i++) {
        System.out.print(((Object[])value)[i]+" ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

  }
}
```

Which will produce:

```
0: B, B, B, 
1: A, A, C, 
2: A, B, A, 
3: A, B, A, 
4: A, B, C, 
5: A, B, C, 
A B A 
A A C 
A B C 
B B B
```